Неверно формируется ссылка в публикациях на изображение Wordpress - Buddypress
Неверно формируется ссылка в публикациях ленты активность Buddypress на изображение.
Вот как ссылка в данный момент выглядит в публикациях ленты активность Buddypress.
<a href="http://localhost:8888/test/../wp-content/uploads/2024/06/8989-48.jpeg" class="lightbox" data-gallery="gallery-6679139136764" rel="nofollow ugc" data-initialized="true"><img loading="lazy" src="http://localhost:8888/test/../wp-content/uploads/2024/06/8989-48.jpeg" alt=""></a>

Добавляются лишние символы, как их удалить не понимаю.
/../

Пыталась вот так исправить проблему но безрезультатно.
function my_plugin_fix_image_paths($content) {
    $site_url = get_site_url();
    
    $content = preg_replace('/(href|src)=["\'](\/wp-content\/uploads\/[^"\']+)/i', '$1="' . $site_url . '$2', $content);

    // удаляю '..//'
    $content = str_replace('/..//', '/', $content);

    return $content;
}


Неверный путь решения. Нужно найти причину (почему и где это происходит), а не лечить последствия.
